# How to convert an ASCII string to base64 in XSL without extensions?

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0

Using Java extensions, converting an ASCII string to base64 in XSL is simple.  But bug [JDK-8004476](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8004476) prevents extension from working if your application is launched via webstart.  Is there any other mechanism that can convert to base64 that I could implement in XSL?

Comment: Base64 is Base64.  There have got to be 100 open-source implementations for Java.

Comment: @HotLicks : Java doesn't help me.  I can't use it because of the webstart bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged your question as XSLT 2.0, the commercial versions of one of the Java XSLT 2.0 processors, namely Saxon 9, provide http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/string-to-base64Binary. Or which Java XSLT 2.0 processor do you use?

Comment: I was using Saxon9 all along.  Don't know how I missed this.  Thanks.